# How can I get my data to display in streamlit from excel?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, streamlit

Only my dataframe is displaying in the web app. Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

file_path = "C\file\path\here"
dataset = pd.read_excel(file_path)

st.set_page_config(page_title="Budget Dashboard", layout="wide")

st.write("Original Budget Data:")
st.write(dataset)

dataset['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(dataset['Amount'], errors='coerce')
dataset['Amount'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

expense_by_category = dataset.groupby('Category')['Amount'].sum()
st.write("Expenses by Category:")
st.bar_chart(expense_by_category)`
```

I've tried upgrading to the latest version of streamlit. Reverting to a previous version. I'm pretty new using streamlit, so any help would be great.

Comment: Can you please show the first few lines of your dataframe/excel structure ?

Comment: when you say only your dataframe is displaying, do you mean that the bar chart is empty or that the bar chart is completely missing from the app?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you're seeing. I get the following output using a sample xlsx file with the same fields (I also included a `null` value just to make sure it's not that).

[image]

Here are a few steps I would take to debug: (1) try using a sample DataFrame that you create, like `dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Amount': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'Category': list('aabbcc')})`. If that works, then you can try (2) importing part of your dataset instead of the entire thing, and see if that renders in the app. I think it's probably something to do with your dataset.